# How to get Request XML from XmlRpcClientProtocol.Invoke

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, request

I'm sending an incorrect request and I wanna know what is wrong with my request.
So, I wanna know XML of that request.
How can I find out request string(XML) after I call this method:

```
using CookComputing.XmlRpc;
private Object ExecuteMethod([CallerMemberName] String method= null, params Object[] parameters)
{
     try
     {
          MethodInfo mein_metoda = GetType().GetMethod(method, BindingFlags.Instance 
          |BindingFlags.NonPublic);
          return Invoke(mein_metoda, parameters);
     }
     catch (Exception ex_greska)
     {
          return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this method and check the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private static void Kwb_klijent_RequestEvent(object sender, CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcRequestEventArgs args)
{
                //Debug.WriteLine(new StreamReader(args.RequestStream).ReadToEnd());
                String zahtjevXml = new StreamReader(args.RequestStream).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.

Comment: I can not. I do not have that kind of privilege.

Comment: As long as the problem has existed for 48 hours, you can mark yourself. This will help others facing the same problem.[Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Arya, I'm gonna mark tomorrow. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You have permission to mark yourself now. If it is convenient, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Put `return` and `Invoke` on separate lines.

```
using CookComputing.XmlRpc;
private Object ExecuteMethod([CallerMemberName] String method= null, params Object[] parameters)
{
     try
     {
          MethodInfo mein_metoda = GetType().GetMethod(method, BindingFlags.Instance 
          |BindingFlags.NonPublic);
          var re = Invoke(mein_metoda, parameters);
          return re; //breakpoint here
     }
     catch (Exception ex_greska)
     {
          return null;
     }
}
```